# Problems to read a XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to read anXML file using 'simplexml_load_file' and it works fine, except with one file that has these tags '',''. When I try to read this file, it fails like it was a blank file. Than I try to remove this character ':' and than it works...

Is there a better way to read this, without removing the ':' character?

here the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeAutorizacao">
            <cUF>43</cUF>
            <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeAutorizacaoLoteResult xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeAutorizacao">
        <retEnviNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
            <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
            <verAplic></verAplic>
            <cStat>104</cStat>
            <xMotivo>Lote processado</xMotivo>
            <cUF>43</cUF>           
            <dhRecbto>2014-10-29T08:49:23-02:00</dhRecbto>
            <protNFe versao="3.10">
                <infProt>
                    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                    <verAplic></verAplic>
                    <chNFe></chNFe>
                    <dhRecbto>2014-10-29T08:49:23-02:00</dhRecbto>
                    <nProt>143140001934763</nProt>
                    <digVal></digVal>
                    <cStat>100</cStat>
                    <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
                </infProt>
             </protNFe>
        </retEnviNFe>
        </nfeAutorizacaoLoteResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please format code & mark which tag is causing issues.

Comment: I need to read last tag <xMotivo> but i cannot open this XML by theses tags <soap:Envelope>

Comment: Why not use SoapClient class? http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient

Comment: How should I use this to read an XML? I never use these classes before, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an XML file you have to escape special chars. Otherwise your XML syntax is broken.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Other think perhaps the Request to fetch die XML is not in UTF-8.

Comment: But this XML isn't made by me, I receive it from server return

Comment: Ok how do you fetch the file? Perhaps your encoding is not correct?

Comment: It is a return from server, I send my XML and the server send to me this XML. It is a financial system.

Comment: Yes but write your code how your send and get the XML file. When you do it with curl for example then you should set the correct encoding

Comment: I'm using a framework, I didn't set any encoding. My framework is nfephp from http://www.nfephp.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate question.

Read answers here:

[parse a SOAP XML response with Namespaces using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929566/parse-a-soap-xml-response-with-namespaces-using-php)

[Parse soap response using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103575/parse-soap-response-using-php)